# Ubuntu 18.04 Pycharm не получается импортировать pcapy

Tags: python, ubuntu, pcap

Не импортирует pcapy, когда ввожу команду в терминал пишет вот это. Что делать? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `pip3 install pcapy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev libpq-dev
```